# not able to copy socket/inode file

Tags: ubuntu, socket, check-mk

I having the file called 'live' in ubuntu, this is the socket/inode type file. This file has the permission as

> ```
> srw-rw-r-- live
> ```

I want to create the copy of the file.

I not able to copy it using cp command from terminal.

Pls anyone tell me how to copy this file or else how to create new socket/inode file in ubuntu.

This file used in check_mk monitoring console.

Thanks....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Unix socket is not a "file" in the way you are thinking.

This file doesn't contain a fixed amount of data which you can copy onto another location. It's not like creating a text file and ending up with `myfile.txt` which doesn't change until you open it again.

Think of the socket file as a "window" into the application, and the data which that window contains will change as the application runs.

If you wish to view what is happening in this socket, you can use `socat` to intercept the data flow in realtime. For example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16045046/how-to-fork-transferred-data-to-a-script-with-socat

Answer (score -2):

You cannot create it, but you can copy from a working system as below to some shared location between the machines and copy from the shared location to the other system.

Machine A

```
cp -rf /dev/SRC shared_directory
```

Machine B

```
cp -rf shared_directory /dev/
```